# Host name server on Amazon Route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, godaddy, amazon-route53

I am planning to move my primary domain from Godaddy to Amazon Route 53. Within godaddy I am currently host two name servers "ns1.mydomain.com & ns2.mydomain.com" both NS point to the IP of my dedicated server. I really want to know is it possible in Amazon Route 53 can make the same structure like Godaddy DNS management? As I don't want to change NS setting of all my domains that currently using above NS1 & NS2?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible by default in AWS Route 53. AWS route53 DNS servers auto generates it's DNS server list.

Read the FAQ to know more https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/

There is a workaround in AWS using White label DNS server feature. See details http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/white-label-name-servers.html

Comment: is it possible in google cloud DNS?

Comment: Even google cloud also auto generates DNS services. If you want to have something like ns1 & ns2. Better have the DNS server hosted on your compure instance EC2 or google compute instance & configure them as per the need.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible and discussed in the following documentation.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/white-label-name-servers.html